# Demodulation of FM signal frequency

Tags: rf, radio, frequency-modulation, ham-radio

After playing with homemade AM radios, I noticed that it is boring to broadcast AM signals all alone. I have also noticed that the AM stations around us, are so limited that I had no other chance than to jump over to FM stations. Of course, it is a bit different how the system works in that case. I have seen many FM demodulator circuits, which are told to work, but these easygoing explanations had not the spice, I need, to make me standalone. I have a pic, which is nice to play around with variable facts inside. So below from Wikipedia:

[image: fm demodulator]

https://wiki.analog.com/_detail/university/courses/electronics/fmd_f5.png?id=university%3Acourses%3Aelectronics%3Aelectronics_lab_fm_detectors

Could you give me a clue, how a FM demodulator would seem to be for 90MHz or 100Mhz FM?

Edit:

I answered my question. The circuit for FM demodulator is just below, I was searching for.

Comment: There's plenty of explanation on the [page that image came from](https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/electronics_lab_fm_detectors), have you read it?

Comment: Looks like a horrible slope detector which is only used these days for teaching

Comment: Get a 4046 phase locked loop IC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I researched on Internet and found useful materials. I managed to make a simulation in LTSpice. Here below is the circuit. I think it would work in reality, too.
The circuit works with 100MHz, modulates a 100k signal to demonstrate the function. After this, it demodulates this signal as expected. It is a FM receiver for most basic.

[image: circuit]

C7, L2 can be seen as signal selector in this case 100MHz frequency.

R1, C1 is a RC filter to get the sent signal, 100k in this circuit.

(to be exactly it should be 79.58nF for C1)

C2 is a decoupling capacitor.

R2 is for example a speaker.